# Flex vertical/horizontal center-align doesn't really center vertically

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm using flex box to align a piece of text (one letter actually) vertically and horizontally.  HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="initial">M</div>
```

with the CSS being:

```
.initial {
    background-color: #fff200;
    color: #ed1c24;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I expect this to completely centre letter **M** inside the circle.  Instead, it's shifted ever so slightly to the top of the container - see this screenshot:

[image]

Adding `line-height: 30px` makes no difference. I can properly vertically centre it by setting `line-height: 34px` - but that's wrong; this fixes displays in firefox, but breaks in chrome. The text really should be centre-aligned!

In firefox, the issue is more pronounced than in chrome.  Here's the [jsfiddle of it](https://jsfiddle.net/vxx89b52/).

Is there any way to centre the text without the extra pixels on line height?

**EDIT:** I appreciate that some people can't replicate the problem.  I also realise I missed the font in my fiddle - the font is set on the document.  The font in use is `font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif`. I see this issue in firefox on both my Mac (El Capitan) and Linux (Mint 17.3). I don't have a windows machine to check.  The biggest problem is the inconsistency.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. The "M" is centered perfectly for me in your fiddle demo in both Chrome and FF. Although the font rendered is Times Roman or another serif type, unlike in your image. Maybe it's a kerning or other typographical issue. Try a different font.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a general solution, but you can use a special font where the *M* character is full height or at least centered (something without ascenders, descenders and the likes)

Comment: Cannot replicate - https://jsfiddle.net/vxx89b52/3/

Comment: Here is `Montserrat`  https://jsfiddle.net/vxx89b52/4/ `Open Sans` and https://jsfiddle.net/vxx89b52/5/, still looks fine.

Comment: letters generates a line-height and stands on the baseline where a block don't http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPRLNx turn the letter into an image, or see what you can do with monospaced font wich might be a little easier to deal with here :)